# Error when importing seaborn in Jupyter notebook

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda, conda

When I try to import `seaborn` I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in __setitem__(self, key, val)
    800             try:
--> 801                 cval = self.validate[key](val)
    802             except ValueError as ve:

KeyError: 'axes.color_cycle'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-334c7a663000> in <module>
      1 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
----> 2 import seaborn as sns
      3 import pandas as pd
      4 import nbashots as nba # this will throw a warning if using matplotlib 1.5
      5 

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/__init__.py in <module>
     11 from .xkcd_rgb import xkcd_rgb
     12 from .crayons import crayons
---> 13 set()
     14 
     15 __version__ = "0.6.0"

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py in set(context, style, palette, font, font_scale, color_codes, rc)
     96     set_context(context, font_scale)
     97     set_style(style, rc={"font.family": font})
---> 98     set_palette(palette, color_codes=color_codes)
     99     if rc is not None:
    100         mpl.rcParams.update(rc)

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/seaborn/rcmod.py in set_palette(palette, n_colors, desat, color_codes)
    489     """
    490     colors = palettes.color_palette(palette, n_colors, desat)
--> 491     mpl.rcParams["axes.color_cycle"] = list(colors)
    492     mpl.rcParams["patch.facecolor"] = colors[0]
    493     if color_codes:

/opt/conda/anaconda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/matplotlib/__init__.py in __setitem__(self, key, val)
    805         except KeyError:
    806             raise KeyError(
--> 807                 f"{key} is not a valid rc parameter (see rcParams.keys() for "
    808                 f"a list of valid parameters)")
    809 

KeyError: 'axes.color_cycle is not a valid rc parameter (see rcParams.keys() for a list of valid parameters)'
```

I'm pretty sure this is because I am using a more recent version of matplotlib and that `color_cycle` was deprecated in matplotlib 1.5. Any suggestions on how I can fix this issue? I have searched the web for hours but haven't been able to find a solution.

Comment: Do you also have a recent version of seaborn installed? (currently 0.10) Your error message seems to hint at version 0.6.0

Comment: Oh wow....yeah that fixed it hahahh. I was doing 'pip install seaborn' and just assumed it was importing a recent version. Thanks!

Comment: _I was doing 'pip install seaborn'_ Be careful! You should use Conda to install packages whenever possible, pip and Conda don't cohabitate perfectly, see https://www.anaconda.com/using-pip-in-a-conda-environment/. Also, be sure that you're using a separate environment for every project/program.